# Tell Mac .app bundle to open command line window

Tags: macos, nsbundle

Is there a way to tell a Mac .app bundle to open the command line for the purpose of printing to stdout? I think it does not really matter, but it is a C++ Qt app.

Comment: No. An app can launch Terminal.app or similar and make it open a window, but that window won't display the output of the app. The stdout of an app isn't connected to any "command line" or Terminal window or anything. Basically, it's a file descriptor opened to `/dev/null`. You could re-open it to some other destination, but none will be a command line or Terminal window unless you build it to be so.

Comment: Thanks, if you reformulate as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that.

An app can launch Terminal.app or similar and make it open a window, but that window won't display the output of the app. The stdout of an app isn't connected to any "command line" or Terminal window or anything. Basically, it's a file descriptor opened to /dev/null. You could re-open it to some other destination, but none will be a command line or Terminal window unless you build it to be so.